# How to call an object from another method in C#

Tags: c#, http

Can anyone help a novice C# beginner?   I'm attempting to call an object created in the same class but a different method. Both methods were called from another class. Below is simplied code.  I've left out other code that the methods perform.  An error indicates the "listener" object isn't recognized in the 2nd method.  Thank you for any help your can offer.

```
// this 1st class calls methods of a 2nd class
public class Lru_operation
{
    // create an object of the 2nd class
    public Lru_Listen LruListen = new Lru_Listen();

    // this method calls two methods from other class   
    public void LruOperation()
    {   
        LruListen.ListenForAag();          // first method call

        LruListen.LruListenAccReq();       // second method call 
    }
}

// this is the 2nd class 
public class Lru_Listen
{
    // 1st method creates an object from a different class (HttpListener)
    public void ListenForAag()
    {
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener(); 
    }

    // 2nd method calls 1st method's object to perform 
    // a method task from a different class
    public void LruListenAccReq()
    {
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.Getcontext();        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to call this across 2 different methods both methods will need access to the value.  Since they are on the same type the easiest way to share out the `listener` value is to make it a field

```
public class Lru_Listen {
  HttpListener listener;

  public void ListenForAag() {
    listener = new HttpListener(); 
  }

  public void LruListenAccReq() {
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.Getcontext();        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is purely within the `Lru_Listen` class - the variable you declared is local to the `ListenForAag` member.  If you make it a class level variable (a field), you won't have this issue:

```
// Make an instance variable:
HttpListener listener;

// 1st method creates an object from a different class (HttpListener)
public void ListenForAag()
{
    // Set the instance variable
    listener = new HttpListener(); 
}

// 2nd method calls 1st method's object to perform 
// a method task from a different class
public void LruListenAccReq()
{
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.Getcontext();        
}
```

Note that, in this case, it would likely be better to set this up in the constructor instead of a method:

```
// this 1st class calls methods of a 2nd class
public class Lru_operation
{
    // create an object of the 2nd class
    // Note that this can be private, since it's only used in this class
    private Lru_Listen lruListen = new Lru_Listen();

    // this method calls two methods from other class   
    public void LruOperation()
    {   
        // No longer required
        // lruListen.ListenForAag();          // first method call

        lruListen.LruListenAccReq();       // second method call 
    }
}

// this is the 2nd class 
public class Lru_Listen
{
    HttpListener listener;

    // use the constructor
    public Lru_Listen()
    {
        listener = new HttpListener(); 
    }

    public void LruListenAccReq()
    {
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.Getcontext();        
    }
}
```

This guarantees that the listener will always be setup properly, even if the user of the class (which may be you) forgets to call `ListenForArg` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to read up on scope. basically your listener does not exist except in the scope of 
the ListenForAag function. Assuming you need to instantiate the listener in the function. however you might be better off with a constructor.

```
public class Lru_Listen
{
 HttpListener listener;
// 1st method creates an object from a different class (HttpListener)
public void ListenForAag()
{
    listener = new HttpListener(); 
}

// 2nd method calls 1st method's object to perform 
// a method task from a different class
public void LruListenAccReq()
{
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.Getcontext();        
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the listener and receive it in the second method, also.

```
public HttpListener ListenForAag()
{
    listener = new HttpListener(); 
    return listener;
}

public void LruListenAccReq(HttpListener listener)
{
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.Getcontext();        
}
```